# Is it possible to write tacit functions in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, tacit-programming

[Tacit or point-free style programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) allows one to create functions without regard to their arguments.  Can this be done in F#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to go with Chuck's answer & Chris Smiths' comment, you could write

```
let digits = string_of_int >> String.length
digits 9000;; // 4
[1; 10; 100] |> List.map digits;; // [1;2;3]
```

When you combine those composition & pipeline operators with higher-order functions, you can do complicated stuff very succinctly:

```
let prodSqrtAbs = Seq.map (abs>>sqrt) >> Seq.reduce (*)
prodSqrtAbs [| -9.0; 4.0 |];;  // 6.0
```

---

**EDIT**:  I just read about J and its implicit fork operator.  That is very powerful.  You can build equivalent higher-order operators in F#, but they won't be applied implicitly.  So, for example, first define `lift` (using explicit arguments)

```
let lift op a b x = op (a x) (b x)
```

and then apply it explicitly

```
let avg = lift (/) List.sum List.length
```

to get something resembling [the J example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tacit_programming&oldid=301960149#APL_.28family.29) on the Wikipedia page you linked to.  But its not quite "tacit."

Comment: Hi, Gabriel. May I ask a question? Does the absence of `implicit fork' operator in FSharp forces me to write only one-argument tacit functions (pack arguments in a tuple/list etc.); but never allows me to write two/three/four/..-argument tacit functions?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. All you need is function composition and currying, and both of these are possible in F#.

```
let compose f1 f2 = fun x -> f1 (f2 x);;
let digits = compose String.length string_of_int;;
digits 9000;; // 4
```

Comment: I'd have written compose the other way round, that way it would look like the >> operator.

Comment: F# has the following operators for doing this sort of thing >>, <<, |>, <|, ||>.